# Angular You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. how to fix?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have app.component.ts which calls two api calls :

```
ngOnInit(){
this.getIt();
this.getIt2();
}

  getIt() {
    const loc = this.myService.getAll('type1').subscribe((data: Location[]) => {
      this.pickupLocations = data;
      this.formGroup.get(LocationFields.pickup).setValue(data[0].getId());
      this.pickupLocationsList = this.pickupLocations.map((data): ISelectOption => {
        return {
          label: data.getName(),
          value: data.getId(),
        };
      });
    },
    (error)=> {
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      this.subs.add(loc);
      this.pickupDateChange(this.formGroup.get(this.LocationFields.pickupDate).value);
    });
  }


  getIt2() {
    const drop = this.myService.getAll('type2').subscribe((data: Location[]) => {
      this.dropoffLocations = data;
      this.formGroup.get(LocationFields.dropoff).setValue(data[1].getId());
      this.dropoffLocationsList = this.dropoffLocations.map((data): ISelectOption => {
        return {
          label: data.getName(),
          value: data.getId(),
        };
      });
    },(error)=> {
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      this.subs.add(drop);
    });
  }
```

When i run ng serve, everything works fine, but later when i build with angular universal :

npm run build:ssr and then node dist/app/server/main.js i get this error :

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:2547451)
    at subscribeToResult (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:2775318)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1997427)
    at Observable_Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952566)
    at CatchOperator.call (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1996815)
    at Observable_Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952420)
    at _task (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1751788)
    at Observable_Observable.Observable.a.observer [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1752133)
    at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952784)
```

This error only appears when i call these 2 functions in ngOnInit() , if i comment them, no error overall. I am not getting any errors in these api calls, they work fine. **How to fix it ?**

Comment: looks like exception is thrown here: How is your application realted to this error?  subscribeTo (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:2547451

Comment: Do any of the answers on the questions about the same error help? [TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47849258/215552), [You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285345/215552) , [ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable in Angular Services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57393553/215552).

Comment: I get error only after universal build. These lines do not show where is the problem, it only show who is throwing (rxjs) the error.

Comment: And no, that didnt help me.

Comment: Can you please add code of myService? Seems like you are missing return statement in getAll() method of myService class. Please attach code of myService.

Comment: The thing is when i remove the second call, error never shows up, why that could happen ?